# Proper way to structure a Cassandra table to show NHL stats

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have been stuck on the correct way to structure my Cassandra tables to hold NHL player stat data.

At first, I had 3 tables structured like:

`CREATE TABLE statsBySeason_points (playerId int, playerName text, season text, goals int, assists int, points int PRIMARY KEY(season, points/goals/assists)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (points/goals/assists DESC);`

and for a query I would use `WHERE season=?`

This way doesn't allow me to have players that have the same points total in the same season since the primary key would end up being the same.

I have also thought about structuring it so each season has its own table and using `PRIMARY KEY (playerId, points)` however this way does not sort by points since they all have unique playerIds.

Basically I cannot think of a way that will allow me to search for players using only the `season` value and have it sorted without having to sort after search. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This allows to search for a season and it can sort by points, goals, assists

`PRIMARY KEY ((season), points, goals, assists, playerId)`